# Symfony3 TimeType form validation GreaterThanOrEqual not working

Tags: php, symfony

i have written form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->...
      ->add ( 'sendTime', TimeType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                    new GreaterThanOrEqual (  ['value'=>"today",'message'=>"error message"] )
            ]
    ]
     )
...
```

and in template:

```
{{ form_widget(formOne.sendTime.hour,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} })  }}
{{ form_widget(formOne.sendTime.minute,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
```

The code checks if the date is not past. But no matter what date given, always error. DateType the type of validation is working properly.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: You're comparing `Time` with an `Date`, aren't you? That can't work.

Comment: It's true, here is mistake. So how can i validate time is not post? I can not find a suitable type of validation. Time validator check is only time.

Comment: How about [DateTime](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DateTime](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html) for this, so you can compare the `Date` and `Time` with the current `Date` and `Time`, which will be set by the `today` parameter in the value of the validator.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('sendTime', DateTime::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new GreaterThanOrEqual (  ['value'=>"today",'message'=>"error message"] )
            ]
        ]
    );
}
```